# Fire Trigger after link click then confirmation page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to push a trigger only after an initial link is click (submit button) and after a confirmation page is reached.  I can create a trigger after the link click variable, however, once the new page is loaded the data layer is reloaded and the original click variable is removed.

Is there a way to persist the initial link click variable across pages?

Answer (score 0):

Once a new page is loaded, all events from the previous page are removed in GTM so there is no way for you to see the linkClick event on the confirmation page.

However, there is a workaround for this: You can create a trigger which fires on some event from confirmation page (like Pageview or Dom ready) and when the value of the built-in variable "Referrer" is set to the previous page (where the submit button is).

Answer (score 0):

You can sequence tags, so you could have one tag for your link click, then another for your confirmation page, and set the confirmation page tag to fire after the link click tag has fired.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6238868?hl=en